# MySQL remove all alphanumeric chars from string except two chars

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this function to remove all alphanumeric chars:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS alphanum; 
DELIMITER | 
CREATE FUNCTION alphanum( str CHAR(32) ) RETURNS CHAR(16) 
BEGIN 
  DECLARE i, len SMALLINT DEFAULT 1; 
  DECLARE ret CHAR(32) DEFAULT ''; 
  DECLARE c CHAR(1); 
  SET len = CHAR_LENGTH( str ); 
  REPEAT 
    BEGIN 
      SET c = MID( str, i, 1 ); 
      IF c REGEXP '[[:alnum:]]' THEN 
        SET ret=CONCAT(ret,c); 
      END IF; 
      SET i = i + 1; 
    END; 
  UNTIL i > len END REPEAT; 
  RETURN ret; 
END | 
DELIMITER ;
```

How do i modify it to allow also these two chars:  `[` , `]` ?

for example:

```
alphanum('hell;o [world] number8$')
```

will give: `hello[world]number8`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
 IF c REGEXP '[[:alnum:]]' THEN
```

To:

```
 IF c REGEXP '[[:alnum:]\[\]]' THEN
```

EDIT:

I guess I never noticed this in the MySQL [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html):

> To include a literal ] character, it must immediately follow the opening bracket [.

```
 IF c REGEXP '[\]\[[:alnum:]]' THEN
```

I'm not sure if the backslash is necessary, so this might work:

```
 IF c REGEXP '[]\[[:alnum:]]' THEN
```

Or:

```
 IF c REGEXP '[[.left-square-bracket.][.right-square-bracket.][:alnum:]]' THEN
```

Comment: it doesn't return anything... empty string.

Comment: @avi . . . Apparently that is (another) difference from "regular" regular expressions.  MySQL does have ways around it.

Answer (score 1):

Simply replace this line

```
IF c REGEXP '[[:alnum:]]' THEN
```

(where you only allow for letters and digits) with

```
IF c REGEXP '[[:alnum:]]' OR c = '[' OR c = ']' THEN
```

or

```
IF c REGEXP '[[:alnum:]]' OR c IN ('[', ']') THEN
```

(where you are also fine with '[' and ']').